# Simple jquery slider effect from the very core

Tags: jquery, css

---

**MAIN EDIT:**

This will help to explain the question better, take a look of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Dgb/), as you can see, the two slides changes using a fading effect, how can I change this effect for an sliding to the left effect like the one you see in tree exploration on [Github](https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter) ?

---

Picture two divs, one called Master and the second one Slave.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="master" style="background-color:#ABC;">1</div>
  <div id="slave" style="background-color:#CBA;">2</div>
</div>
```

The content on the slave div gets updated via ajax only when a button get press on the master div (already programed), on success (the ajax call finish and the div slave is updated) I want the Master div to slide to the left while the slave div slide too.

On the first state the user can only see the Master div, slave is invisible, when the button is pressed master slide goes out to the left and Slave slides to ocupy the original master position (just a simple slider). As I said, I already program all the basic interactions on jquery and the server side code (php + ajax), but I have NO idea how to set the css in order to accomplish this, for the animations im using a simple `$('#div').slideLeft(400);`

I dont want to use any existant jquery plugin or html5 or css3 (if possible), just want to keep it simple, but again, im not very good front-end dev and figuring out the css to get this right is driving me crazy. Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**
I meant when i said slideLeft:

```
$(this).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
$(this).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

Comment: Mmmm, `slideLeft`? I'm pretty sure that doesn't exist in jQuery.

Comment: You right, there is slideDown and up, but the solution will be something like slideLeft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the css2 "clip" property, adding one extra container div [to make the clip work] and by slightly modifying your fiddle code to rely on `animate` instead of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, this effect is possible. However, the solution isn't as simple as you might like it to be, or as clean.  Neverless, it works.

HTML:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:200px;height:100px;left:100px;">
    <div style="position:absolute;clip:rect(0px,200px,100px,0px);overflow:none;width:200px;height:100px">
    <div class="table-cont" style="display: none; position:absolute; background-color:#ABC;width:100%;height:100px;"></div>
    <div class="table-coupons" style="display: none; position:absolute;top: 0px; background-color:#CBA;width:100%;height:100px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$('div.table-coupons').css({opacity:0,marginLeft:200});

     calltable();
        function calltable()    {
$('div.table-coupons').css('display','block');
$('div.table-cont').css('display','block');

            $('div.table-coupons').animate({opacity:0,marginLeft:200},{ duration: 300, queue: false,complete:function(){$(this).css('display', 'none')}});
            $('div.table-cont').html('HELLO World! <a href="#" class="coupon_link">Next</a>');
            $('div.table-cont').animate({opacity:1,marginLeft:0},{ duration: 300, queue: false });
            $('a.coupon_link').click(function() { next_slide(); });
        }
        function next_slide() {
$('div.table-coupons').css('display','block');
$('div.table-cont').css('display','block');

            $('div.table-cont').animate({opacity:0,marginLeft:-200},{ duration: 300, queue: false, complete:function(){$(this).css('display', 'none')}});
            $('div.table-coupons').html('HELLO again! <a href="#" class="back_link">Back</a>');
            $('div.table-coupons').animate({opacity:1,marginLeft:0},{ duration: 300, queue: false });
            $('a.back_link').click(function() { back_slide(); });            
        } 
        function back_slide() {    
            calltable();            
        }            

 });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/97pcj/1/

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your code, but if you can figure out the CSS that puts your elements where you want them, before and after, you can use the [jQuery animate function](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate). All you have to do is have them in an initial position, then call the animate function on them with the parameters of the final position you want them in. jQuery will take care of the rest. for example, let's say you need to move it 400px to the left of its original position which had a margin-left of 0px:

```
$("#div").animate({marginLeft: -400px});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to move left or when you say "slide" you mean as in slideUp() and slideDown(). 
If you mean the latter

```
$(this).animate({width:'toggle'},400);
```